# Enabling SSL for S3, serve index.html by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with which I want to use SSL. I also want to serve up index.html by default.

When accessed over http, `my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/` serves up index.html. However, AWS doesn't maintain an SSL certificate for this subdomain so it cannot be accessed over SSL. AWS does maintain an SSL certificate for `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/` which does resolve, as expected. But, that domain doesn't serve up index.html by default (even though index.html is set as the index document).

Is there a solution to this problem that does not require CloudFront (which is currently set up) or flexible SSL with CloudFlare? I'm trying to reduce the cost without sacrificing security.

Comment: Read the pricing tables carefully.  In the US and Europe, using CloudFront + S3 is essentially the same cost as using S3 alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the "Static Website Hosting" option for hosting websites from S3, only HTTP can be used. HTTPS is not supported. This is done using the `my-bucket.s3-website-*` URL.

The `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` endpoint is not an endpoint for serving up a website. It's simply an endpoint for the S3 API. This is why it supports HTTPS. So you can GET, POST, etc. to this endpoint when you're authenticated (or as anonymous if public ACLs are configured).

But it's not a website endpoint and won't serve `index.html` or the 404 page automatically.

To act as a website and use SSL, you must use a fronting service such as CloudFront.